# Calling pkg and Stored procedure, but it give me syntax error

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, plsql, java-stored-procedures

I am trying to call the pkg and the procedure in java, as below:

```
public void rebuildIndexes() {
        Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("BEGIN BFPA_ARCHIVING.rebuild_archiving_indexes; END;");
        query.executeUpdate();
}
```

BFPA_ARCHIVING is the package and rebuild_archiving_indexes is the procedure.
When I tried to test it, it gave me this error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "BEGIN BFPA_ARCHIVING[*].REBUILD_ARCHIVING_INDEXES; END; "; SQL statement:
BEGIN BFPA_ARCHIVING.rebuild_archiving_indexes; END; [42000-167]
Error Code: 42000
Call: BEGIN BFPA_ARCHIVING.rebuild_archiving_indexes; END;
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="BEGIN BFPA_ARCHIVING.rebuild_archiving_indexes; END;")
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "BEGIN BFPA_ARCHIVING[*].REBUILD_ARCHIVING_INDEXES; END; "; SQL statement:
BEGIN BFPA_ARCHIVING.rebuild_archiving_indexes; END; [42000-167]
Error Code: 42000
Call: BEGIN BFPA_ARCHIVING.rebuild_archiving_indexes; END;
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="BEGIN BFPA_ARCHIVING.rebuild_archiving_indexes; END;")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:308)
```

I am not finding the exact way to call the pkg, any idea?

Comment: Where did `[*]` come from? It shouldn't be here, I presume. `BFPA_ARCHIVING[*].REBUILD_ARCHIVING_INDEXES`

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out, but I can't find if this is given from pkg...

Comment: You're calling ```createNativeQuery``` but the argument is not a query. It is a stored procedure. I would say you need to call ```createNamedStoredProcedureQuery``` instead

Comment: @KoenLostrie actually, in this way I did before to execute the procedure since I just need to call this in the method.
I am not sure if createNamedStoredProcedureQuery works in this case

Comment: Well... the error shows "error in SQL statement". I'm assuming that is because the string you are passing isn't a sql statement at all. Just my 2 cents, I'm not a java person